# How to use a function results in the same angular controller

Tags: angularjs, function, scope, controller, output

I am trying a simple angular logic and its not working for me. I would appreciate any help with this.

my controller has something like this:

```
    $scope.UpcomingEvents = {}

    $scope.someID = 3;

    $http.get(BaseUrl().url + 'jury/UpcomingEvents?someID=' + someID)

    .success(function (response) {

        console.log(response);

        $scope.UpcomingEvents = response;

    })
```

This controller gives correct results in my html when I call it like this in my html file:

```
    <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in UpcomingEvents">
             <td>{{data.EventID}}</td>
             <td>{{data.Title}}</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
```

However I want to modify UpcomingEvents table in the angular controller and then display a new table onto the html. I am having no luck doing this.
   In my controller file, whenever I save a value of Upcoming Events, it just would not save.

I am doing it like this in my controller file, just below where I call that http get function, just like so:

```
         $scope.UpcomingEvents = {}
         $scope.someID = 3;
         $http.get(BaseUrl().url + 'jury/UpcomingEvents?someID=' +   
         someID)
          .success(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          $scope.UpcomingEvents = response;
       })

       $scope.hello=0;

       //the line that just does not work
       $scope.hello= UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;
```

This last line is not saving that first value of Upcoming Events. 
Am I doing something wrong?

I call this in my html as

```
             {{hello}}
```

and its giving me no results.

However if I output the value like this in my html, it gives the correct output:

```
              {{ UpcomingEvents[0].EventID }}
```

It executes correctly and gives me result. but whenever I save into another variable it just does not work. I am missing something in the way we save values in angular controller.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put

```
$scope.hello= UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;
```

inside the `success` call, like this:

```
$http.get(BaseUrl().url + 'jury/UpcomingEvents?someID=' + someID)
  .success(function (response) {
    $scope.UpcomingEvents = response;
    $scope.hello= $scope.UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;
 });
```

`$http.get` is an asynchronous action, more specifically it doesn't return a value itself, but rather a `$q` promise. The `success` function is a callback for when the promise is resolved. Assigning `UpcomingEvents[0].EventID` to `$scope.hello` outside of the callback resulted in `$scope.hello` being assigned `undefined`. To put it simply, this assignment was executed before the callback could happen, when `UpcomingEvents` was still empty.

Also, Your assignment should look like this

$scope.hello=**$scope**.UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;

As You declared `UpcomingEvents` inside the $scope. It doesn't exist outside of it.

Comment: A question that I have following this: If I wanted to use $scope.hello from this success function outside the success function, how can I use this? I want to use this $scope.hello in another function outside the success function. More specifically, I want to use this $scope.hello value in another place in my controller.  Is there a way to do it?  Thanks

Comment: In this case You need to be sure, that the asynchronous action is finished, before a proper value is stored in `$scope.hello`. You could initialize `$scope.hello` with some default value before the callback function, so that You don't get `undefined` when You access it elsewhere, but the complete solution depends on what Your flow is.